# Cast object as List of unknown type

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a list of unknown type that comes from a serialization as JArray, i want to set it as value in a PropInfo but List type is unknown at runtime.

```
var propInfo = someClass.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault();

var typeM = Type.GetType("ClassName, ClassLibrary");
var propValue=SomePropValueObject;//this was List if typeM 
Type listType = typeof(List<>).MakeGenericType(typeM);

propInfo.SetValue("SomeLib",propValue as List<????listType>);
```

Any direction would be great

Comment: Can you describe more about your issue? What type of list do you expect? What classes do you intend to convert to? Why is a List of unkown type unsatisfying?

Comment: is a list of custom objects non-standard

Comment: I tried to write an answer, but what you're trying to do doesn't quite make sense so there is no "right" way to do it. This question might work better if you could show what you're trying to do if all the types are known, and show that code, and then ask "what if the types are unknown?" But I think the answer will likely still be that you can't. Often if we're using reflection for something like this it's already gone wrong. The best thing is to figure out how to do it with known types so you don't have to use reflection.

Comment: The types are not really known they are unknown at runtime as they are loaded via reflection , i can get their names from AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()